# How to Pass <Div> content to servlet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, servlets

I tried pass the content of an entire div in form action url using JS. but on servlet side when i try to get this request param as String, i am getting it as [object Object].

This is my form and JS

```
<div id="paraContent">
   Content in jsp
</div>
<form id="form1" action="/sendEmail.email.send.html" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="contentValue1" name="contentValue1"/>
   
    <input type="button" value="place order" onClick="formSubmit()"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var divContent = $('#paraContent');
    $("#contentValue").val(divContent);

    function formSubmit() {
        var form = document.getElementById("form1");
        var str = "/sendEmail.email.send.html?contentValue=" + $('#paraContent');
        form.action = "/sendEmail.email.send.html?contentValue=" + $('#paraContent');
        form.submit();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could copy the div's content into a div when the form is subbmitted.

```
<form id = "form1" action="/sendEmail.email.send.html" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="contentValue1" name="contentValue1"/>
    <c:Set var="contVal" value="ddd"/>
    <input type="button" value="place order" onClick="formSubmit()"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function formSubmit() {
        $("#contentValue1").val($("#paraContent").text());
        var form = document.getElementById("form1");
        var str = "/sendEmail.email.send.html?contentValue=" + $(paraContent);
        form.action = "/sendEmail.email.send.html?contentValue=" + $(paraContent);
        form.submit();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Awesome :D glad to be of service!

Answer (score 0):

try by changing the

`$(paraContent)` to `$("#paraContent");` and also

`$("contentValue").val(divContent);` to `$("#contentValue").val(divContent);`

Comment: Sorry.. actually in original code i have added '#' in all places.. just forgot to mention it here when i typed :) thanks for your answer though :)

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use ajax post in order to send data from div to your servlet

```
<div id="paraContent">
       Content in jsp
</div>



<script>
    $(document).ready(function (){
        var data=$("#paraContent").text();
     $.ajax({ 
    url: "YOUR SERVLET", 
    type: "POST", 
    data: { "data": data}, 
    success: function(data) { 
    console.log(data); 
    } 
    });
        });
</script>
```

In your servlet

```
String datafromdiv=request.getParameter("data");
```

Try this instead on a button click function .....

Comment: Thanks for replying vicky :) actually i am using the above solution to retrieve div content and using Ajax call as you have mentioned to send it across to servlet :)